# How to Style The Django Forms?

Tags: django, forms, widget, styling

So, I am making a project, and I need a couple of settings, in the form of BooleanFields.

so,

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    notifications = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    email_notifications = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    restricted_mode = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    hide_subscriber_count = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    private_channel = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)
    playlists_private = forms.BooleanField(label="", required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ['notifications', 'email_notifications', 'restricted_mode', 'hide_subscriber_count', 'private_channel', 'playlists_private']
```

How to use widget=forms.BooleanField(attrs={"id":"notifications", "class":"notifications"})?
How to stick an id to the notifications field or email_notifications field?

Comment: If you are just trying to style the field/s, take a look at https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: Thank, I will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

In your forms.py, try this:

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields= ('notifications', 'email_notifications', 'restricted_mode', 'hide_subscriber_count', 'private_channel', 'playlists_private')
        widgets = {
            'notifications': forms.RadioSelect(attrs= {
                 'id': 'notifications'}),
            'email_notifications': forms.RadioSelect(attrs= {
                 'class': 'email_notifications'})
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is, it is giving me a dropdown instead of a checkbox which I want!

Comment: Did you try my code? RadioSelect will give checkbox. I am confused how you get dropdown instead when you use RadioSelect.

Comment: Yes, I have tried your code, but RadioSelect gives me a dropdown with the options YES or NO

Comment: hmm, that's odd, because it is working just fine at my end. 1) are you using {{form}} in the template? 2) do you have other css is interfering with the django default format?

Comment: Well, I am using bootstrap, and crispy_forms. I am doing {{ form|crispy }. ``` {{ load crispy_forms_tags }